# Edit Microsoft Word 2007 table of contents indent?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007

I am using Microsoft Word 2007 and I have an automatically-generated table of contents. However, my margin is 2cm all round and the page numbers are right-against the margin.

I would like to bring the page numbers towards the center of the page. How do I do this?

Comment: [Word: Modify Table of Contents tab settings](https://cybertext.wordpress.com/2009/05/12/word-modify-table-of-contents-tab-settings/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I would like to bring the page numbers towards the center of the page. How do I do this?

> 1. Click once anywhere in the Table of Contents.
> 2. Open the Table of Contents tab:
>
>    - Word 2003: Select Insert > Reference > Index and Tables from the menu. Select the Table of Contents tab.
>    - Word 2007: Click the References tab, click the Table of Contents button, then select Insert Table of Contents from the bottom
>        of the drop-down menu. The Table of Contents tab is the only tab
>        displayed.
> 3. Click Modify.
> 4. Select TOC 1, then click Modify again.
> 5. Click Format, then select Tabs.
> 6. Select the tab stop position you want to change (e.g. 13.5 cm).
> 7. Click Clear.
> 8. Set a new right tab stop position the same width as the body text of your document (e.g. 17 cm):
>
>    - Type 17 cm in the text box at the top.
>    - Select the Right alignment option.
>    - Select the 2 (dotted) leader option.
>    - Click Set.
>    - Click OK to return to the Modify Style window.
>    - Click OK again to return to the Style window.
>
>    [image]
> 9. Repeat steps 4 to 8 for the other styles (TOC 2, TOC 3) that have tab stops you want to modify. Use the same value (e.g. 17 cm) for
>      the right tab stop position for each.
> 10. When you’re finished, click OK to close the Style window.
> 11. Click OK.
> 12. Click OK when you’re asked to replace the Table of Contents.
> 13. Check everything’s as you want it; make further modifications as necessary.

Source [Word: Modify Table of Contents tab settings](https://cybertext.wordpress.com/2009/05/12/word-modify-table-of-contents-tab-settings/)